# How to configure AOP in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I haven't used AOP before in Spring before, so I"m just trying to get a simple example working with my application.

This is the code I used:

```
/**
 * The product cache aspect manages the product cache.
 *
 */
@Aspect
public class ProductCacheAspect {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ProductCacheAspect.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private MemcachedClient memcachedClient;

    @AfterReturning(
            pointcut = "execution(* com.ideafactory.mvc.products.common.services.ProductService.get(..))",
            returning= "result")
    public void logAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        logger.debug("Executed point cut");
        logger.debug(result);
    }
}
```

And I think I have it configured correctly:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ideafactory"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableScheduling
**@EnableAspectJAutoProxy**
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
...
}
```

I also have the pom.xml set up to import AspectJ.

But when I try to execute the get method on the ProductService, it doesn't enter the aspect method. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it now.

Can anyone suggest what could be wrong?

========== Method being advised =============

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Product get(long productId) {
        logger.entry();


        Product product = null;


        // check the cache first, if it's in cache we'll use that.
        product = (Product) memcachedClient.get(Product.getCacheKey(productId));


        if (product == null)
        {
            product = productRepository.findOne(productId);
            // now we initialise the product.
            if (product != null) {
                Hibernate.initialize(product.getImageSets());
                Hibernate.initialize(product.getTags());
                Hibernate.initialize(product.getVariantOptions());
                Hibernate.initialize(product.getVariants());
                Hibernate.initialize(product.getChildRelationships());
                memcachedClient.set(Product.getCacheKey(productId), 3600, product);
            }
        }

        logger.exit();
        return product;

    }
```

=========== Class definition =============

```
package com.ideafactory.mvc.products.common.services;
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService
{
...
}
```

============ Adding POM.xml =================

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ideafactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>java_ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>2.0-rc2</log4j.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.7.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.2</aspectj.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.26</mysql.version>
        <jackson-json.version>2.3.1</jackson-json.version>
        <jackson-mapper-asl.version>1.9.13</jackson-mapper-asl.version>
        <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.1</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
        <commons-upload.version>1.3.1</commons-upload.version>
        <jmagick.version>6.6.9</jmagick.version>
        <jadira.core.version>3.2.0.GA</jadira.core.version>
        <joda-money-version>0.9.1</joda-money-version>

        <!-- Cache -->
        <spy-memcache-verion>2.11.4</spy-memcache-verion>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Logging dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
             <version>2.0</version>
         </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Data JPA dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SpringSecurity dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependencies required for AOP Programming -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DB dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-mapper-asl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Velocity for email templates -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Validations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- dependency on SOLR data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- This is for spring JPA framework auditing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-money</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-money-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>${jadira.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-upload.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.im4java</groupId>
            <artifactId>im4java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cache Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.spy</groupId>
            <artifactId>spymemcached</artifactId>
            <version>${spy-memcache-verion}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: I originally misread the pointcut thinking that you were trying to advise a field itself, but then noticed that you were trying to advise a method called `get` in your class.

Do you actually have a method called `get()`?  It would seem a little odd.  Can you please post the class method that you are trying to advise?

Comment: I just updated the post. I do use get, because it's easy to type :)

Comment: Can you post the spring startup logs as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your pointcut is trying to advise the Interface execution which IIRC is not possible (ie: the interface is not the code that is executed).  You should be advising an implementation.  Additionally, as suggested by @Angad, you may need to also annotate it with `@Component` such that Spring actually autoscans for it (unless you have a custom auto detect filter).  I do not believe that Spring will automatically detect/instantiate @Aspect beans.

So you have a couple of options.

1: Build your pointcut to actually advise the implementation itself:

```
@AfterReturning(
        pointcut = "execution(* com.ideafactory.mvc.products.common.services.ProductServiceImpl.get(..))",
        returning= "result")
public void logAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
    logger.debug("Executed point cut");
    logger.debug(result);
}
```

2: Write your pointcut to advise the interface and any classes that implement it (note the `+` symbol at the end of the interface name):

```
@AfterReturning(
        pointcut = "execution(* com.ideafactory.mvc.products.common.services.ProductService+.get(..))",
        returning= "result")
public void logAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
    logger.debug("Executed point cut");
    logger.debug(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric I did already add the @Component, and I tried advising the Impl class as well, but it still won't fire. I just posted the POM.xml which I've checked the dependencies, but maybe I've missed something.

Comment: Do you see the aspect bean being loaded/instantiated by Spring in the startup logs?  And this may be a silly question, but you do have something calling/executing the `ProductServiceImpl.get()` method?  Of course, I presume the Aspect and the ProductServiceImpl are all part of the same project?  The next step I would try is make your pointcut more wild.  Just set it to execution( * *.*(..)) for example and see if that is ever triggered at all.

Comment: Definitely in the same project and definnitely being called. I set the pointcut to the generic (* *.*(..)) it's caused startup to fail because of some class in the JPA auditing framework not supporting aspect-J?? 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Post-processor tried to replace bean instance of type [org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener] with (proxy) object of type [org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b405c2f] - not supported for aspect-configured classes!'

Comment: I can see the messages coming through though before it errors, so the pointcut is executing.

Comment: Next step, try to make your pointcut specific to your pacakges.  ie: (* com.ideafactory..*(..)) and see if that properly advises your methods.  There is actually a way in AspectJ to show the weaving logs, but not sure if it is applicable the same way when using Spring AOP.

Comment: Ok I did try it, but get various startup fails, mostly on core JPA code because the JPA template must implement a final class. To avoid that error I have to augment a class within quite a low level package which isn't working. I'll try to get logging working and see if I can see an issue - maybe there's an error being written to a logger that's not working (I've had issues with my logging configuration and it doesn't print Spring core output)..

Comment: Are you using log4j?  Enable debug logger at the root logger (will generate way too much log information), but at least you might be able to see what you need.  Also, if you are having trouble with your logging, try using a `System.out.println("*****HERE*****)` in your aspect and search for the string in your console output.  The aspect might in fact be working properly and you just aren't seeing the logs.  If anything, the fact that you are having so much difficulty when you make the pointcut vague implies that the aspect seems to be recognized.

Comment: No it's okay actually, I did have problems but must have fixed them. I went back and enabled trace on the root logger. I can definitely see something happening with the AOP Proxying when it starts up, but it's a little hard to trace. But there's definitely no trace reference to the AOP proxy classes when I call the method. I might park this issues for a day or two and come back to it! I need to move onto something productive lol.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to use AOP to define caching on methods. If so you may want to take a look at [Simple Spring Memcached](https://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/). It provides caching in memcached through custom annotations (`@ReadThroughSingleCache, @UpdateMultiCache, @ReadThroughAssignCache, ...`) or Spring Cache annotations (`@Cacheable`).